# Windows git installation does not have git ls-remote

Tags: git, jenkins

I have installed jenkins-2.121.1 in windows System. Also installed git Git-2.18.0-64-bit.exe. I also configured git Location URL in Jenkins > advanced tools configurations.

While creating a project, in the source code management for Git, i gave the git repository URL as my source code location. Soon i am getting error message as:

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: C:\Program Files\Git ls-remote -h  HEAD

Can anybody help on this?

Comment: `git ls-remote <repo_url>`.

Comment: Try running the same command manually in a command prompt. If it succeeds it means something is not correctly configured in Jenkins (what is the working directory of your cloned repository?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use git bash console under Windows for `ls-remote`. So far I found `ls-remote` only can be called under Git Bash on windows. I was facing the same issue while was using npm, and do `npm install --verbose` under Windows git bash so that 'ls-remote' can be called during the npm install process, it won't do verbose as the default.